# POM missing dependency org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender Eclipse Neon.2

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

Building Java DXA 1.7 for Web 8.5 following http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-and-debugging-dxa-java-with-web-8-5-on-amazon instructions to get a working java dxa 1.7 we have 34 errors in the Eclipse error log for plugin org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.

example:

> "The POM for com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.5.0-1012 is missing, no dependency information available."

How do I resolve these warnings?

Addition error messages:
[image]

Comment: Can you please post those messages you get? And also I am curious if you can build this without Eclipse with pure Maven. You need Maven 3.2.2+ for this.

Answer (score 4):

Particularly this message:

> "The POM for com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.5.0-1012 is missing, no dependency information available."

seems like an issue in libraries. Also it's interesting that apparently Eclipse has different mechanism of resolving Maven dependencies (but it's only a guess).

Fortunately, this one is easy to resolve. In WebApp's `pom.xml` you need to declare these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>cil</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>content-client-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0-1013</version>
</dependency>
```

This excludes all `content-client-api` artifacts and includes it again with a right version.

Comment: Please can you be more specific.

Comment: Please can you be more specific.
This is already in the dependencyManagement section

Comment: Do you mean you've added this to your Web App's pom.xml, but it doesn't help?

Comment: It was already in the POM dependencyManagement section.

Comment: Is should rather be in `<dependencies/>` section. The fact you declare anything in `dependencyManagement` doesn't mean it's now used. You should declare a corresponding dependency.